# How can I create more buttons of the same appearance (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, button, location

Please, can you help me how can I create more buttons of the same appearance. I have graphics structure for buttons in a separate class. A function for creating buttons I have in windows form.

**Step 1)** 
Class for graphic button structure:

```
class GraphicClassStructure : GraphicPosition
{
    public Button resetTree = new Button();

    public void CreateClassButtons()
    {
        // Reset tree
        resetTree.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        resetTree.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.reset;
        resetTree.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        resetTree.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        resetTree.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        resetTree.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        resetTree.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        resetTree.Name = "resetTree";
        resetTree.Size = Size[0][5];
        resetTree.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    }
}
```

**Win forms function for control buttons.**

```
private void classMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classStructure.ClassAllButtonsVisible();
    classStructure.CreateClassButtons();
    this.Controls.Add(classStructure.classBackround);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                classStructure.resetTree.Location = classStructure.Location[0][2];
                break;
            case 1:
                classStructure.resetTree.Location = classStructure.Location[0][3];
                break;
            case 2:
                classStructure.resetTree.Location = classStructure.Location[0][4];
                break;
        }
        classStructure.resetTree.Click += new EventHandler(resetTreeOneEvent_Click);
        classStructure.resetTree.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(resetTree_MouseEnter);
        classStructure.resetTree.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(resetTree_MouseLeave);
        classStructure.resetTree.Tag = i;
        this.Controls.Add(classStructure.resetTree);
    }
}
```

The current problem is that the creation of the buttons is in the class "GraphicStructure" but in class it creates only one button. Although I can embed into windows form to the function, but I'd like to have graphic buttons and functions separately. Can you help me please?.

**Control:**

```
private void resetTreeOneEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        switch ((int)button.Tag)
        {
            case 0:
                // First Button Clicked
                break;
            case 1:
                // Second Button Clicked
                break;
            case 2:
                // Third Button Clicked
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or second idea. I have created a button that does nothing, but has a graphical Structure. Then create three additional buttons that are already doing something, but again have no graphics and just need to get those buttons to do something cloned from graphic button that does nothing.

**I try use this but i still saw only one button:**

```
private void classMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classStructure.ClassAllButtonsVisible();
    classStructure.CreateClassButtons();
    this.Controls.Add(classStructure.classBackround);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button = classStructure.resetTree;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                button.Location = classStructure.Location[0][2];
                break;
            case 1:
                button.Location = classStructure.Location[0][3];
                break;
            case 2:
                button.Location = classStructure.Location[0][4];
                break;
        }
        button.Click += new EventHandler(resetTreeOneEvent_Click);
        button.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(resetTree_MouseEnter);
        button.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(resetTree_MouseLeave);
        button.Tag = i;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Second idea work (i saw three buttons) if i commented this:

```
button = classStructure.resetTree;
```

But if i commented this part code so all three button is again without graphic structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need buttons with same appearance, then create your custom button inherited from `Button` and use it instead of standard `Button`:

```
public class TreeButton : Button
{
    public TreeButton()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        BackgroundImage = /* set some image  */
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;       
        Size = /* set size */
        UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    }
}
```

If you want buttons to behave differently, then assign different click event handlers to different buttons.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I need a little different solutions. I have created a button that does nothing, but has a graphical Structure. Then create three additional buttons that are already doing something, but again have no graphics and just need to get those buttons to do something cloned from graphic button that does nothing.

Comment: @RadekTarant sorry, didn't get you. Buttons usually don't have logic - they just raise events which invoke handlers